# Get HashMap from RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a requirement to get a global HashMap from RDD[HashMap]. For example, the RDD is RDD[HashMap[Key, value]]. I want to get a global HashMap from this so that I can use this HashMap for enriching messages present in other RDD.

Could anyone please help me how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Does the **RDD** have only one element?, or do you want to merge all maps in one _(which strategy do you want for merging)_?, or is it a **RDD** of tuples `(Key -> Value)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So like the comment says, you'll need a merge function. Assuming a simple hashmap merge works for you such as if the keys/values are unique, then you can merge it into a local map using something as simple as `rdd.reduce(_++_)`. Then you'll want to broadcast it so that its efficiently sent to each executor once. Once it's in the broadcast variable then this can be used within your RDD operations on other RDDs such as enriching messages as you said.

```
val brodcast = sparkContext.broadcast( rdd.reduce(_++_) )
```

And this can be used by using `broadcast.value`